# Excel formula to extract yes

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with different columns with all have the value `Yes` or `No`. I want in my last column a formula that extract a result of all the previous columns.

If all the values are `No`, the result has to be `No`
Is one or more values `Yes`, the result should be `Yes`

I don't know which formula I can use for that. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"Yes") > 0,"Yes","No")
```

Change A1:C1 to the range of interested columns

Comment: The problem is: I don't have a range (A1:C1), I have my values in different columns (A1;A3;A5), but I can't use that in de countif function. How can I put columns instead of a range?

Answer (score 0):

Try using OR function. you can get syntax https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0

Answer (score -1):

You just need nested OR functions for each column.  Here's a sample with 3 columns:

```
=OR(A1="yes",OR(B1="yes",C1="yes"))
```

[image: excel screenshot]

For additional columns, add another OR around the existing, with one argument testing the this code, and then add your new column as the other argument.